# Typescript implement conditional props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have the following component, which can either contain an image or a text. Hence in JSX I check whether there's an image (because that means there must not be text vice versa), and then either display the image or text.

How can I define this behavior with TypeScript types?

I `BlockCtaDoubleData`, which is always available, and **EITHER** `BlockCtaDoubleImageData` **OR** `BlockCtaDoubleTextData`.

I tried the following, but Typescript keeps throwing an error for `props.text` & `props.image`, but not for `props.headline`.

How so?

```
interface BlockCtaDoubleData
{
    headline: string;
}

interface BlockCtaDoubleImageData extends BlockCtaDoubleData
{
    image: string;
    alt: string;
}

interface BlockCtaDoubleTextData extends BlockCtaDoubleData
{
    text: string;
}

export type BlockCtaDoubleProps = BlockCtaDoubleTextData | BlockCtaDoubleImageData;

export function BlockCtaDouble(props: BlockCtaDoubleProps)
{
    return (
        <div>
            {props.headline}
            {props.image ? (
                <img src={props.image} alt={props.alt}/>
            ) : (
                {props.text}
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

FYI: The error is saying that the respective prop is not existing in the counter type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish `BlockCtaDoubleImageData` and `BlockCtaDoubleTextData` you will need a type guard.

```js
import React from "react";

interface BlockCtaDoubleData {
  headline: string;
}

interface BlockCtaDoubleImageData extends BlockCtaDoubleData {
  image: string;
  alt: string;
}

interface BlockCtaDoubleTextData extends BlockCtaDoubleData {
  text: string;
}

export type BlockCtaDoubleProps =
  | BlockCtaDoubleTextData
  | BlockCtaDoubleImageData;

const isBlockCtaDoubleImageData = (
  a: BlockCtaDoubleProps
): a is BlockCtaDoubleImageData => a.hasOwnProperty("image");

const isBlockCtaDoubleTextData = (
  a: BlockCtaDoubleProps
): a is BlockCtaDoubleTextData => a.hasOwnProperty("text");

export function BlockCtaDouble(props: BlockCtaDoubleProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.headline}
      {isBlockCtaDoubleImageData(props) ? (
        <img src={props.image} alt={props.alt} />
      ) : (
        props.text
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

A type guard is a function that returns `x is Type`. You need to implement it in such way: it returns true if x is Type and false otherwise. The exact condition is up to you.

### Edit with answer for question from comments

You cannot achieve it with your approach. You will have to use discriminated union.

```js
interface BlockCtaDoubleData {
  headline: string;
  type: "image" | "text";
}

interface BlockCtaDoubleImageData extends BlockCtaDoubleData {
  image: string;
  alt: string;
  type: "image";
}

interface BlockCtaDoubleTextData extends BlockCtaDoubleData {
  text: string;
  type: "text";
}

export type BlockCtaDoubleProps =
  | BlockCtaDoubleTextData
  | BlockCtaDoubleImageData;

export function BlockCtaDouble(props: BlockCtaDoubleProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.headline}
      {props.type === "image" ? (
        <img src={props.image} alt={props.alt} />
      ) : (
        props.text
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
<BlockCtaDouble headline="as" text="xd" type="image" image="xd" />
```

will throw an error:

```
Type '{ headline: string; text: string; type: "image"; image: string; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & BlockCtaDoubleTextData) | (IntrinsicAttributes & BlockCtaDoubleImageData)'.
  Property 'text' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BlockCtaDoubleImageData'.
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes it work. One more thing though - calling the component, I'm still able to mix the probs, how can I make TypeScript tell me, that `< BlockCtaDouble headline="Test" image="some image" text="some text">` is not possible.

Comment: I suppose you would need a generic component for that, will check if it is possible in TSX.

Comment: @Tim I've added possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the existing answer, you can use a terser behavour [using `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator). You can do the following:

```ts
interface BlockCtaDoubleData
{
    headline: string;
}

interface BlockCtaDoubleImageData extends BlockCtaDoubleData
{
    image: string;
    alt: string;
}

interface BlockCtaDoubleTextData extends BlockCtaDoubleData
{
    text: string;
}

export type BlockCtaDoubleProps = BlockCtaDoubleTextData | BlockCtaDoubleImageData;

export function BlockCtaDouble(props: BlockCtaDoubleProps)
{
    return (
        <div>
            {props.headline}
            {("image" in props) ? (
                <img src={props.image} alt={props.alt}/>
            ) : (
                {props.text}
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

[TS Playground to show the `in` behaviour](https://tsplay.dev/9Wvekm)

Comment: Thanks, how can I additionally tell TS that calling the component like `<BlockCtaDouble headline="Test" image="some image" text="some text"/>` (basically just mixing types again) is forbidden?

Comment: Being a [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), TypeScript does not stop you from having extra fields. So, a `type T = {a : string}` is compatible with `{a: 'adc', extra: 123}`. In your case, `BlockCtaDoubleProps` is valid as long as it contains `headline, image, alt` attributes, if you add extra attribute names `text`, it is still valid `BlockCtaDoubleProps`. Similarly, if it contains `headline, text` keys, it is valid `BlockCtaDoubleProps`, but if happen to contain `image` and / or `alt` as extra key, it is valid.

Comment: @Nishant is right. Although you may use discriminated union to achieve it.